# In how many ways can one change a $5 bill

Tags: python

I need to propose an algorithm and implement it in python. It has to  show in how many ways one can change a $5 bill in coins of 1, 5, 10, 25, 50 cents and 1 dollar. The maximal amount of coins will be the change in 500 coins of 1 cent and the minimal one will consist of 5 coins of 1 dollar each. The code below can run only if the number of coins considered is less than 20. Beyond that limit running of the code becomes very slow. Thus, it is not possible to reach all over to a length of 500 coins. What should I change in the code ? Thanks.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as c
def change(n, k):
    S = []
    L = [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
    for i in c(L, k):
        if sum(i) == n:
            S.append(i)
    return len(S)

def change_range(n):
    j = 0
    for i in range(5, 501):
        j += change(n, i)
    return j    

print(change(500,5)) 
print(change_range(500))
```

Comment: Have you heard of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100026/ways-to-make-change-for-a-dollar-how-to-optimize-with-constraints

Comment: @user Your code is very inefficient. Instead of generating every possible group of coins and checking if the sum is correct, consider trying to only generate the combinations with the desired sum. From there, perhaps you can figure out how to count possibilities without generating them

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is very inefficient. Currently, you are generating every possible group of coins and checking if the sum that group is correct. A more efficient approach would be to use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to solve the problem recursively.

To recursively characterize the solution, let C(n;[c<sub>1</sub>,...,c<sub>k</sub>]) denote the number of ways of giving change for n cents using coins with values c<sub>1</sub>,...,c<sub>k</sub>; we'll say that C(0;[c<sub>1</sub>,...,c<sub>k</sub>]) = 1 (since a group of no coins is the only way to have zero cents).

Try to answer the following questions:

- What is C(n;[1])?
- How can you get C(n;[c<sub>1</sub>,...,c<sub>k-1</sub>,c<sub>k</sub>]) using the values of C(m;[c<sub>1</sub>,...,c<sub>k-1</sub>]) for m = 0,1,...,n?

Using these answers, try to write an algorithm to calculate the values of C(m;[1]) for m = 0,1,...,n, then the values of C(m;[1,5]) for m = 0,1,...,n, and so on until you have the values of C(m;[1,5,10,25,50]) for m = 0,1,...,n. Then, use those values to get the number you're after, namely C(n;[1,5,10,25,50,100]).